# Текст налезает на картинки (иконки)

Tags: html, css

Почему-то текст начал налезать на иконки, перепробовал почти все методы, но ничего не помогает :( подскажите что делать? **Ниже прилагаю скрин**

[ССЫЛКА НА СКРИН (](http://f3.s.qip.ru/3GS55j8X.png) http://f3.s.qip.ru/3GS55j8X.png )

Comment: код кидай. скриншот тут не поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без исходного кода, в голову лезит только padding изменить на более

Comment: или 4 span-a подряд, или 4 дива с float: left